# Update default <option> content in a <select> with a attribute directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I searched a lot and I tried combinations: with transclusions, with $compile, priorities... but nothing. I hope, that your experience helps me.

I have a attribute directive for **select** directive/elements. I want change the default text or the default option when I am doing some operations in background, like loading the content of select vía API request. Well, I can change some properties of ***select*** like disabled or not without any problem, but when I try to access **to the content** of  (that only contains the default placeholder or option) I have problems, because I haven't compiled HTML.

**This is my  element** with "background" attribute directive that tries to control the default **option**:

```
<select ng-model="test" ng-options="v as v for v in ['one', 'two']" background="isLoading">
  <option value="">NotBinded:{{ 'hello world' | uppercase }}</option>
</select>
```

Observe that the are two parts: normal text and binded text.

And this is **the directive**:

```
angular
 .module('app')
 .directive('background', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     transclude: false,
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       // This prints: NotBinded:{{ 'hello world' | uppercase }}
       // In conclusion: it is not compiled
       console.log(element.children().text())
     }
 }
});
```

I need to store the initial text of option (with text compiled) for restore it when the process ends up, because I will replace temporary with some "loading text".

**The example in plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/ox2rJgudoFEfrrHyJIX1?p=preview (note: I observed that console.log() is empty in plunker. In normal project the outputs is correct. I don't know why)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you need to apply this directive to a `<select>`? Why not just do something simple like this: `<option val="">{{isLoading ? 'loading...' : 'select'}}</option>`

Comment: I though about it. I want concentrate all logic of loading in a directive. For example, I will add a ngDisabled or disabled property when it is loading. Or may be I could change some class property to show a spinner also. I agree with you, that it is the fastest and easy way, but I consider this problem interesting, but I have no idea how to solve it